# Use infinitescroll in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a $http function that retrieves some data from the server.
I want to load more data when scrolling, but I am not really sure how I can get this working.

This is the $http function:

```
$scope.getSubData = function(id){
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/getSubData',
    params: {
      subId: id  
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response){
    $scope.sub = response.data.sub;
  });
};
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in sub">
  <tr ng-repeat="message in item.messages">
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.date}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive which will call the method `getSubData()` when scrolled.
This directive will be placed at the parent `div` like this:

```
<div when-scrolled="getSubData()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in sub">
    <tr ng-repeat="message in item.messages">
      <td>{{message.title}}</td>
      <td>{{message.date}}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

The directive will go something like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Now, as the `getSubData()` will be called each time you'll scroll, you need to update the definition to concat the new data.

`$scope.sub = $scope.sub.concat(response.data.sub);`

You can refer this link for more details:
https://coderwall.com/p/cl7zyg/api-calls-and-infinite-scroll-with-angularjs

Comment: Hi There! Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer.